# creating a line graph in python

Tags: python, loops, graph, line

I need to create a line graph using python without using `matplotlib.pyplot` using the formula y = m*x + c. The format of the graph needs to look like this:

[image: desired output]

How can I create a custom graph like this? So far, I have tried the following:

```
r=int(input("enter number rows "))
c=int(input("enter number of columb"))
i=0
j=c
for row in range(r):
    for col in range(c):
        if col==0:
        print ("|",end="")
    elif row==(r-1):
        print ("--",end="")
    elif row == i or col == j:
        print ("*",end="")
        i=i+2
        j=j-1
    else:
        print(end=" ")

print ()
```

Comment: What is your question, specifically?

Comment: How is your python code even running? Your indentation is all messed up

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py

Answer (score 1):

Other than matplotlib there are several other libraries which do the same work. Like Plotly, ggplot, seaborn etc.

https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

ggplot for plotting a line equation:
https://yhat.github.io/ggpy/notebook.html?page=build/docs/examples/Plotting%20a%20Line%20Equation.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. `m` is your slope and `c` is your intercept. The trick is to just check the distance from the line to the point x and y. If the distance is close enough then you can draw your symbol (`*`). The larger the threshold you give for distance, the thicker the line will turn out to be.

```
import math

def intercept(px, py, m, c):
    # Find distance between point (px, py) and line (y=mx+c)
    dist = abs(m*px - py + c) / math.sqrt( m*m + 1)
    if dist <= 0.5:
        return True
    else:
        return False

rows=20
cols=20
m = 0.25
c = 0
for row in range(rows):
    y = rows - row - 1
    for col in range(cols):
        x = col
        if intercept(x, y, m, c):
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print("")
```

**Output for m=1**

[image]

**Output for m=0.4**

[image]

Since I did this in jupyter notebook it was not a monospaced font hence m=1 is not a perfect 45 deg slope, but if you try it in your terminal or any monospaced output it should work just as expected.

Comment: thank you very much i will get back to with my progress.

Comment: @AlexMiller  Please accept/upvote my answer if it is the correct solution to your problem